# python Преобразование русского текста в строку и обратно

Tags: python

Подскажите, что я делаю не так. Есть файл с русским текстом в кодировке UTF-8. Необходимо преобразовать этот текст в байты, а потом обратно.
Однако пытаясь сделать так:

```
subject = str.encode('utf-8')
subject = subject.decode('utf-8')
```

ничего не выходит.

Comment: Без [mcve] сложно чем-то помочь. Выведите тип/значение переменной str для начала.

Answer (score 1):

Вы, ИМХО, Позабыли в `str.encode()` указать собственно что нужно энкодить.

```
ru_txt = '''Подскажите, что я делаю не так. 
Есть файл с русским текстом в кодировке UTF-8. 
Необходимо преобразовать этот текст в байты, а потом обратно.
Однако пытаясь сделать так:
'''
b_ru_txt = str.encode(ru_txt, 'utf-8') # Можно b_ru_txt = ru_txt.encode('utf-8')
print(b_ru_txt)
to_str_ru = b_ru_txt.decode('utf-8')
print(to_str_ru)
```

Comment: Нужно указывать кодировку в encode/decode т.к. если ее нет, то будет браться системная, а она не всегда UTF-8

Comment: Согласен - косяк. Поправил